# How to check if a value of my array exists inside another object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have an array that I receive oid and name data and I need to compare if my oid value exists within an object.

This is my array:

```
const data  = [
    {
        "oid": "nbfwm6zz3d3s00",
        "name": "",
    },
    {
        "oid": "g74rvmr3cxpc0",
        "name": "",
    }
]
```

This is my Object:

```
const myObj = {
  nbfwm6zd3s00: 'test value 1',
  g74rvmrcxpc0: 'test value 2'
)
```

How could I check if the oid value inside my data array exists in "myObj"?

Comment: What does `ref` do with the object?

Comment: To clarify, you want to know if there is a key in your object that exists in your array?

Comment: @RhettHarrison yes

Comment: @DemiPixel Sorry, it was a mistake. I already removed the ref in my object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Object.keys(obj) to run through all the keys then loop through your data. I changed a key so there was a matching key in this example:

```
const data = [
  {
    oid: "nbfwm6zzd3s00",
    name: ""
  },
  {
    oid: "g74rvmr3cxpc0",
    name: ""
  }
];

const myObj = {
  nbfwm6zzd3s00: "test value 1",
  g74rvmrcxpc0: "test value 2"
};

for (const key of Object.keys(myObj)) {
  data.forEach((d) => {
    if (key === d.oid) {
      console.log("Found: ", key);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    oid: "nbfwm6zzd3s00",
    name: ""
  },
  {
    oid: "g74rvmr3cxpc0",
    name: ""
  },

];

const myObj = {
  nbfwm6zzd3s00: "test value 1",
  g74rvmrcxpc0: "test value 2"
};



console.log( data.filter(item => Object.keys(myObj).includes(item.oid) ))
```